# fseek not reading all the data?

Tags: c++, installation

I am making a c++ installer and I have appended both the file to extract and an 8 byte filesize of the file to extract within the program, to the executable. My program exits on a file read error, whats going wrong? To note I don't have any knowledge about c file managing, apart from what I've learned today. I am writing the file test_before.tar.gz, which is 161 bytes, the executable is 12335 bytes long and the filesize file is 8 bytes long, containing 0000161. What's wrong? Ask for more info if needed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout << "Opening the executable as read-only!" << endl;
    FILE *exeFile; // The executable file pointer
    FILE *outFile; // The file to write pointer

    // Check whether a file name was supplied
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        cout << "Please enter the file to write!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Open the executable as read-only
    if((exeFile = fopen(argv[0], "rb")) == 0)
    {
        cout << "Error opening the executable!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "Getting the executables size!" << endl;

    // Get the files size
    fseek(exeFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    int size = ftell(exeFile);

    cout << "Reading ofset!" << endl;   

    // Read the ofset bytes contained in the last 7-bytes
    char filesize_char[9];
    fseek(exeFile, -8, SEEK_END);
    fgets(filesize_char, 9, exeFile);

    // Convert
    int filesize = atoi(filesize_char);
    int ofset = (size - filesize) - 8;

    cout << "The ofset size is " << ofset << " bytes!" << endl;
    cout << "The file size is " << filesize << " bytes!" << endl;

    cout << "Reading the file to extract!" << endl;

    // Create the variable to contain the file and goto the ofset
    char* contents = new char[filesize + 1];
    fseek(exeFile, ofset, SEEK_SET);

    // Read the file to extract
    if(fread(contents, sizeof(char), filesize + 1, exeFile) != sizeof(contents))
    {
        // Error has occured
        if(feof(exeFile)) {
            cout << "Premature end of file!" << endl;

            // Delete variables so they dont "leak"
            fclose(exeFile);
            delete[] contents;

            return 1;
        } else {
            cout << "File read error!" << endl;

            // Delete variables so they dont "leak"
            fclose(exeFile);
            delete[] contents;

            return 1;
        }
    }

    cout << "Writing the file to " << argv[1] << "!" << endl;

    // Write the file to extract
    if((outFile = fopen(argv[1], "wb")) == 0)
    {
        cout << "Error opening the file to write!" << endl;

        // Delete variables so they dont "leak"
        fclose(exeFile);
        fclose(outFile);
        delete[] contents;

        return 1;
    }

    fwrite(contents, 1, sizeof(contents), outFile);

    //delete variables
    fclose(exeFile);
    fclose(outFile);
    delete[] contents;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Platform?  You probably need to open `"rb"`.

Comment: use fread rather than fgets. fgets is meant for strings and stops on a new line

Comment: You are making a c++ compiler? Really?

Comment: @Gabe, typo :/, installer not compiler

Comment: The while loop is mysterious.  You are using strlen(contents) with contents never initialized.  Nothing good can happen after that.

Comment: @Hans, doesn't new char[], pad the string with 0s, so strlen would return 0 which works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the while loop at all. After all, you already allocated the memory that would contain all your data. Move file pointer to the start of data `fseek(exeFile, ofset, SEEK_SET)`, then use `fread` to read it as whole, and then use `fwrite` to write it into `outFile`.

You should open your `exeFile` and `outFile` with `"rb"` and `"wb"` flags otherwise your code would work reliably only with text data.

Comment: @Will03uk You get it quite right: but you have to use `filesize` directly when reading — it's the size of data you want to read as you evaluated before. The return value of `fread` should be `filesize`, why do you compare it to 5?

`fwrite` parameters are wrong because `sizeof(contents)` is 4 for 32 bit code and 8 for 64 bit code. But you want to write `filesize` bytes.

I see no point in calling `rewind` because you always call `fseek` before reading data.

Comment: so what is the exact fwrite call, then i'll vote this the correct answer?

Comment: @Will03uk Parameters to `fwrite` are the same as to `fread`: `fwrite(contents, 1, filesize, outFile)`. And you have to change your if to this one: `if(fread(contents, sizeof(char), filesize, exeFile) != filesize)`.

Comment: @Will03uk One more time: `sizeof(contents) == sizeof(char *)`, because `contents` is a pointer, not an array. If it was declared as `char contents[10]`, then `sizeof(contents)` would be 10.